# how to change protectionLevel normal to Dangerous

Tags: java, android

I need to change protection Level of a permission from normal mode to dangerous mode.

i tried like this but it didn't work.

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:label="my_permission" android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

An Android application cannot change the `protectionLevel` of a system-supplied permission. The first `<uses-permission>` in wins, and the system's `<uses-permission>` is applied well before your app is even installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"` **is invalid**.
For using internet you can just use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`, **but NOT**  `<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`